# Repairing a worn out PCB switch pad

Tags: pcb

[image: PCB with one switch pad not working]

The `ON` pad on the top left of this board is not closing the circuit anymore when the silicone button comes down on it. It doesn't look nearly as oxidized or dirty ad the other 3 switch pads, which are working correctly.

The fault isn't in the buttons as I have switched them around with no change, this remaining the only non-working button.

Is there anything visible that shows what the problem is with this pad? Or anything I can test on it?

Edit: added reverse of board.

[image: Reverse of PCB]

Comment: Try some isopropyl-alcohol to clean it.

Comment: Maybe one of the vias has opened up, or maybe there's a trace on the other side of the board which is corroded right through. Try following the one circuit that is unique to that particular key switch and check continuity on either side of vias and traces by gently scraping a bit of the solder mask off and probing. It's also possible it's so low resistance that the particular key is not responding, so first clean the board with 99% IPA and a toothbrush as @Transistor suggests. Allow to dry thoroughly before testing.

Comment: Did some cleaning with 96% alcohol with no effect, need to get my hands on a probe now to actually test the trace. This is the last button on the `+` trace from the battery so most of that trace should be fine as the other buttons all depend on it. The other side goes into the black box but looks like it could have some damage on the hole where it passes through the component side.

Comment: Isopropanol is your friend as always. If that does not work, a light scrub with steel wool.

Comment: Or a rub with a lightly abrasive pencil eraser.

Answer (score 2):

See image below with test points added to your photos. Do these tests:

- Verify test points #1 and #2 are connected (if not then the trace between them is cracked)
- Carefully scrap off a little solder mask before the via (hole near #3), verify #3 and #4 are connected (if not then the trace between them is cracked)
- Again, carefully scrape off a little solder mask before via (hole near #5), verify #3 and #4 are connected to #5 (if not then via is damaged)
- Inspect #6 carefully, it appears thin to me and could be a cracked or damaged trace

To fix a trace, just scrape some of the solder mask before and after the crack, then apply solder (first clean with IPA and use flux) to bridge the gap. Or add a small thin strand pulled from wire.

To fix the via (hole), just scrape solder mask from both sides, then insert thin strand of wire through hole and solder on both sides. If via is plugged with solder mask, which appears to be the case, just pick out with small pin.

[image]